# Newspaper theme tagdiv not rendering shorcode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I don't know why the shortcode is not working on the post page, but working on the home page, that is the WordPress, I used the newspaper theme.

[image: Website screenshot]

I did change the theme to latest, then it stops working it is showing like that.